# Can't source .tmux.conf file: "Usage: source-file path"

Tags: linux, tmux

I noticed my tmux config file was named `.tmux.confg` instead of `.tmux.conf` so I changed it and I now can't source it for some reason.  I get the error `Usage: source-file path`.

I was going to copy and paste the console output of the source-file command with my path to .tmux.conf, both with and without quotes, but apparently getting copy-to-clipboard functionality for zsh is some kind of H. P. Lovecraft nightmare.  I'm positive the file named `.tmux.conf` is located in my home directory, and the path I'm using is `~/.tmux.conf`.  And I could prove all this if not for the reason previously mentioned.

I'm certain I must be overlooking something obvious.

Comment: I figured it out.  It was a syntax error in the .tmux.conf file, nothing to do with the usage.

Comment: Maybe answer the question yourself to get it closed off, or remove entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was a syntax error in the .tmux.conf file, nothing to do with the usage.